# como lidar com um json que contem varios resultados usando python

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

Olá,estou fazendo um script python que pega o nome de um filme e retornar alguns dados para o usuario(titulo,ano etc). Estou usando a api omdbapi, porém minha duvida não é com relação a ela e sim em como lidar o seguinte json http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=b34f7b7b&s=star+wars&type=movie, quando uso o parametro t ele me retorna os dados de um filme só então é de boas porém quando uso s ele retorna varios resultados e estou tendo problemas em como printar isso.
cod:https://github.com/Mathe13/movie_search/blob/master/movie_search.py

Comment: A recomendação é colocar o  código aqui junto com a questão. Se o programa for muito extenso, o ideal é chegar a um trechinho que possa reproduzir de forma independente o problema que você esta encontrando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só alterar a linha 49:

```
for i in resposta.get('Search'):
    print('teste')
    print_movie_data(i)
```

Comment: obrigado,ajudou mt.
dei um up no codigo pra mostrar os resultados através da paginas tbm